# How can I get a Docker image's label if the label name has a "." in it?

Tags: templates, go, docker

The docker inspect command can be very useful for getting the labels on a Docker image:

```
# -*- Dockerfile -*-
FROM busybox
LABEL foo="bar"
LABEL com.wherever.foo="bang"
```

For simple label names, the inspect command has a `--format` option (which uses Go templates) that works nicely.

```
$ docker build -t foo .
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Labels.foo }}' foo
bar
```

But how do I access labels that have a dot in their name?

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Labels.com.wherever.foo }}' foo
<no value>
```

I'm writing this in a bash script, where I'd like to avoid re-parsing the JSON output from `docker inspect`, if possible.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `index` function is what I was looking for. It can lookup arbitrary strings in the map.

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ index .Config.Labels "com.wherever.foo" }}' foo
bang
```

Comment: In case others have this issue, in Windows Powershell I had to add either a backslash or a backtick before the double-quotes, both seem to work.  Otherwise I got the error **function "com" not defined** 
   
`$ docker inspect -f '{{ index .Config.Labels \"com.wherever.foo\" }}' foo
bang`

Comment: Similar error fixed by double quote escaping \" is `Template parsing error: template: :1: function "com.wherever.foo" not defined` (PowerShell v.5),

Comment: Does not work in docker-compose, is there any different option?

Comment: How do you get more paths after that index? I tried `{{ index .Foo.Bar "whatever" .OtherKey }} and that doesn't work